# How to connect client and server in Unity using Mirror

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, server

I'm having trouble getting my client to connect to my server using Mirror in Unity. It seems like the call just hangs until disconnected.

## **Server**

A GameObject in scene with 2 components: Telepathy Transport and ArenaManager (derives from Mirror.NetworkManager).

```
public override void Start()
{
    base.Start();

    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler<AuthenticateMessage>( OnAuthenticate, false );
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler<MatchConfirmedMessage>( OnMatchConfirm, false );
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler<PlayerLoadedMessage>( OnPlayerLoaded, false );
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler<PlayerPreppedMessage>( OnPlayerPrepped, false );
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler<PlayerUnpreppedMessage>( OnPlayerUnprepped, false );
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler<PlayerLoadoutMessage>( OnPlayerLoadout, false );
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler<PlayerStatusMessage>( OnPlayerStatus, false );
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler<PlayerEventMessage>( OnPlayerEvent, false );
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler<PlayerTauntMessage>( OnPlayerTaunt, false );
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler<PlayerReconnectingMessage>( OnPlayerReconnecting, false );
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler<RequestRematchMessage>( OnRequestRematch, false );

    #if RUN_LOCALLY
    GetComponent<TelepathyTransport>().port = (ushort)m_Port;
    NetworkServer.Listen( 9999 );

    StartCoroutine( CheckIP() );        // spits out my external IP address for checking
    StartCoroutine( GatherTitleData() );    // just gathers some game-related data
    #else
    // PlayFab related work to get the remote server IP...
    #endif
}

public override void OnServerConnect( NetworkConnectionToClient nConn )
{
    base.OnServerConnect( nConn );

    // this is not getting hit on the server...
}
```

## **Client**

I have the same setup as the server. Telepathy Transport component and my ArenaManager that derives from Mirror.NetworkManager. The IP I use to connect is the external IP of the machine running the server. I've already port-forwarded to make sure that's not an issue. Before I did that, the host denied connection, now my attempt to connect just hangs.

```
void ConnectClient( string address, int port )
{
    NetworkClient.OnConnectedEvent = OnClientConnect;
    NetworkClient.RegisterHandler<MatchFoundMessage>( OnMatchFound, false );
    NetworkClient.RegisterHandler<MatchReadyMessage>( OnMatchReady, false );
    NetworkClient.RegisterHandler<PrepStatusMessage>( OnPrepStatus, false );
    NetworkClient.RegisterHandler<PlayerLoadoutMessage>( OnPlayerLoadout, false );
    NetworkClient.RegisterHandler<StartBattleMessage>( OnStartBattle, false );
    NetworkClient.RegisterHandler<OpponentStatusMessage>( OnOpponentStatus, false );
    NetworkClient.RegisterHandler<OpponentEventMessage>( OnOpponentEvent, false );
    NetworkClient.RegisterHandler<BattleRefreshMessage>( OnBattleRefresh, false );
    NetworkClient.RegisterHandler<EndBattleMessage>( OnEndBattle, false );
    NetworkClient.RegisterHandler<OpponentLeftMessage>( OnOpponentLeft, false );
    NetworkClient.RegisterHandler<OpponentRematchMessage>( OnOpponentWantsRematch, false );
    NetworkClient.RegisterHandler<PlayerTauntMessage>( OnOpponentTaunt, false );
    NetworkClient.OnDisconnectedEvent = OnClientDisconnect;
    NetworkClient.OnErrorEvent = OnClientError;

    GetComponent<TelepathyTransport>().Port = ( ushort )port;
    NetworkClient.Connect( address );
}

public override void OnClientConnect()
{
    base.OnClientConnect();

    // this is never hit, the call to Connect hangs until it times out and I get disconnected
}
```

I've opened my port for forwarding on the hosting machine. I've entered the external IP and the hardcoded port to connect, but I can't seem to successfully connect.

I'm not experienced with network development, so it's plausible I'm doing this entirely wrong. Regardless, I can't seem to figure out what step is missing.

I greatly appreciate any help anyone can provide. Thank you very much in advance!
-Matt

Comment: "'ve opened my port for forwarding on the hosting machine.I've entered the external IP and the hardcoded port to connect, but I can't seem to successfully connect." so you put your routers IP into your pc? you need to open port forwarding on the router, not the pc..   which makes it not a programming issue but a technical one

Comment: I did open the port on the router, sorry. That was a poor way for me to say that.

Comment: Is there a better place to go for an answer to this? Unity forum has no response...